# Get word counts in strings of words in a list using python

Tags: python, pandas, count, cpu-word

Starting with a pandas data frame where the first column is made up of comment strings with the other columns being features of single words. For each row I would like to get a count of how many times each word appears in that row's comments cell. I have the list of words (feature columns) as a list called, "wordList" and am trying something like this but having trouble getting it working and the counts back into the data frame:

```
def word_count(comments):
    for word in wordList:
        return comment.count(word)

df.comments.apply(word_count)
```

What I have:

```
comments        |  hello  |  this  |   is   |  the  |  comments  |  blah  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is the 1st |         |        |        |       |            |    
comments here   |         |        |        |       |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
the 2nd comment |         |        |        |       |            |    
is is here this |         |        |        |       |            |
```

What I want:

```
comments        |  hello  |  this  |   is   |  the  |  comments  |  blah  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is the 1st |    0    |    1   |   2    |   1   |     1      |    0
comments is here|         |        |        |       |            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
the 2nd comment |    0    |    1   |   2    |   2   |     0      |    0
is is here the  |         |        |        |       |            |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your coment column into a list and explode.

Apply get dummies. That will tabulate frequency of occurrence

Reindex with the list of words you wish to check

Aggregate the frequency and join to the df.coments column

Code below:

```
g=pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(df1.coments.str.split('\s').explode())).reindex(columns=['hello', 'this','is','the','comments','blah']).fillna(0).astype(int)

pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,0]).join(g.groupby(level=0).sum(0))




     coments                         hello  this  is  the  comments  blah
0    this is the 1st comments here      0     1   1    1         1     0
1  the 2nd comment is is here this      0     1   2    1         0     0
```

Comment: I used this example with a short word list of just 6 words but my actually list is hundreds. 

Will this work just the same if I replace the "columns =" list with just my word list variable?

Comment: Should work. Dont see why it should not. Happy to help further if needed. Ping me a comment and will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` to extract (only) the words in your word list, then use `value_counts`:

```
pattern = '|'.join(word_list)
(df.comments.str.extractall(rf'\b({pattern})\b')[0]
   .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
   .reindex(word_list, axis=1, fill_value=0)
)
```

Output (note that this also has a column named `comments` as in the original dataframe)

```
0  hello  this  is  the  comments  blah
0      0     1   1    1         1     0
1      0     1   2    1         0     0
```